# Mathematics of symmetry in chaos

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, symmetry, chaos-theory

I'm a neuroscience PhD student.
Recently I became so interested in the mathematical equations involving order and disorder and complex plane. I read a book named "Symmetry in chaos" by Martin Golubitsky. It's about the generation of symmetrical patterns using simple chaotic equations based like this 
 [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1HoC.png)

I'm really willing to learn about the mathematics of this kind, to understand what is done here because it's so related to my field and I just know some calculus, so I ask from you great guys to guide me by either introducing some books or
teaching me directly. Actually I would love to have a remote advanced math teacher and I'm willing to pay for the services. Thanks.